# [drake in C++]: Declare an abstract input port in a controller to get contact result from multibody plant

Tags: c++, drake

Recently, I am trying to construct a "BaseContoller" to control the motion of "Atlas" in "Drake".

To get the contact result of the multibody plant in the controller, I tried to declare an **abstract input port** in the controller leafsystem, which is to be connected to the **contact results output port** of the multibodyplant.

Then, in the Calc method of torque output port, I tried to get contact result from the abstract input port.

All the code can be compiled successfully, but during the runtime "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" occured. I wonder if I have missed something.

```
// Atlas.cpp

int do_main(){
  
  systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder;
  auto [plant, scene_graph] = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(
      &builder,
      std::make_unique<MultibodyPlant<double>>(
          FLAGS_mbp_discrete_update_period));

  const std::string full_name = 
          FindResourceOrThrow("drake/../../../../home/hampton/Atlas/urdf/atlas.urdf");
  multibody::Parser(&plant).AddModelFromFile(full_name);
 
  // register the ground as visual geometry and collision geometry；
  ...

  plant.Finalize();
  plant.set_penetration_allowance(FLAGS_penetration_allowance);
  plant.set_stiction_tolerance(FLAGS_stiction_tolerance);

  // connect the controller;
  auto controller = builder.AddSystem<systems::controllers::BaseController<double>>(plant);
  builder.Connect(controller->get_output_port_control(),
                                      plant.get_applied_generalized_force_input_port());
  builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(),
                                      controller->get_input_port_estimated_state());
  builder.Connect(plant.get_contact_results_output_port(),
                                      controller->get_input_port_contact_result());

  auto constant_zero_torque = builder.AddSystem<systems::ConstantVectorSource<double>>(
                Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(plant.num_actuators()));
  builder.Connect(constant_zero_torque->get_output_port(),
                                    plant.get_actuation_input_port());


ConnectContactResultsToDrakeVisualizer(&builder, plant, scene_graph);
geometry::DrakeVisualizerd::AddToBuilder(&builder, scene_graph);

auto diagram = builder.Build();


std::unique_ptr<systems::Context<double>> diagram_context =
         diagram->CreateDefaultContext();

// Do the initialization of context;
...

// Set the simulator;
auto simulator =
      MakeSimulatorFromGflags(*diagram, std::move(diagram_context));
  simulator->AdvanceTo(FLAGS_simulation_time);
  simulator->set_publish_every_time_step(true);

  return 0;
}
```

```
//BaseController.h

template <typename T>
class BaseController : public LeafSystem<T>{

public:

    DRAKE_NO_COPY_NO_MOVE_NO_ASSIGN(BaseController);

    BaseController(
            const multibody::MultibodyPlant<T>& palnt);
    ~BaseController();

    const InputPort<T>& get_input_port_estimated_state() const {
        return this->System<T>::get_input_port(input_port_index_state_);
    }

    const OutputPort<T>& get_output_port_control() const{
        return this->System<T>::get_output_port(output_port_index_control_);
    }

    const InputPort<T>& get_input_port_contact_result() const {
        return this->System<T>::get_input_port(input_port_index_contact_result_);
    }
    
private:

   // Output Calc Function;
    void CalcOutputTorque(const Context<T>& context, 
                                                        BasicVector<T>* force) const;
    
   ...

    const multibody::MultibodyPlant<T>*  const multibody_plant_;

    InputPortIndex input_port_index_state_{0};
    OutputPortIndex output_port_index_control_{0};
    InputPortIndex input_port_index_contact_result_{0};

    const int q_dim_{0};
    const int v_dim_{0};

    drake::systems::CacheIndex multibody_plant_context_cache_index_;

};
```

```
// BaseController.cpp

template <typename T>
BaseController<T>::BaseController(
    const multibody::MultibodyPlant<T>& plant)
    :  multibody_plant_(&plant),
       q_dim_(plant.num_positions()),
       v_dim_(plant.num_velocities())  
{
    DRAKE_DEMAND(plant.is_finalized());

    input_port_index_state_ = 
        this->DeclareVectorInputPort(
            "Estimated State", 
            q_dim_ + v_dim_).get_index();

    output_port_index_control_ = 
        this->DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "Control Torque", 
            v_dim_,
            &BaseController<T>::CalcOutputTorque).get_index();

    input_port_index_contact_result_ = 
        this->systems::LeafSystem<T>::DeclareAbstractInputPort(
            "Contact Result",
            Value<multibody::ContactResults<T>>()).get_index();
            // *AbstractValue::Make(multibody::ContactResults<T>())).get_index();
    
    auto multibody_plant_context = multibody_plant_-> 
                    System<double>::CreateDefaultContext();

    
    multibody_plant_context_cache_index_ =
      this->SystemBase::DeclareCacheEntry(
              "multibody_plant_context_cache",
              *multibody_plant_context,
              &BaseController<T>::SetMultibodyContext,
              {this->input_port_ticket(
                  get_input_port_estimated_state().get_index())})
          .cache_index();
}

...

template <typename T>
void BaseController<T>::CalcOutputTorque(
    const Context<T>& context,
    BasicVector<T>* force) const{
   ...
    const auto& contact_results =
        get_input_port_contact_result().template Eval<multibody::ContactResults<T>>(context);
    
    // const AbstractValue* abstract_value = 
    //             this->EvalAbstractInput(context, input_port_index_contact_result_);
    // const multibody::ContactResults<T>& contact_result_ = 
    //             abstract_value->get_value<multibody::ContactResults<T>>();
  
}

template class BaseController<double>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code snippets and created a buildable/runnable version of it on my side. I don't have the specific atlas URDF that you reference in your -- I used one of "ours" instead (`"drake/examples/atlas/urdf/atlas_convex_hull.urdf"`). The good news is it produced a segfault. (I don't know if it's the *same* segfault, but it produced one.)

When I rebuilt in debug and ran it through the debugger, I found the segfault came when computing the mass matrix (specifically, `drake::multibody::internal::MultibodyTree<double>::CalcMassMatrix` at `multibody/tree/multibody_tree.cc:1513`. That invocation *is* being triggered by `BaseController::CalcOutputTorque()`.

Now, I don't know where your segfault is coming from. So, before investigating that particular segfault with my particular URDF, I'd recommend you do the same and report on where the segfault is happening.

-------- EDIT ------------------

Your code is pointing toward a defect in Drake. You've introduced an algbraic loop. The inputs of the plant depend on the output of the controller, but the input of the controller depends on the output of the plant. This scenario *should* be detected when you build the diagram, but it isn't. That's something for us to address.

The way to solve this is to put a system in between them where the loop is "broken". This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965256/the-issue-with-modelling-the-force-torque-sensor-in-drake/66970891#66970891) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413974/can-spatialinertia-be-bypassed-when-simulating-a-multibodyplant-in-drake/68441938#68441938). This second solution proposes a low-pass filter to serve as the break. You can also simply use a zero-order hold on the controller output (modeling the controllers real-world frequency).

Comment: The debugger only tells "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" without any other tip messages. But it seems that the problem only occured when calling `const auto& contact_results = get_input_port_contact_result().template Eval<multibody::ContactResults<T>>(context);`. I have post the full source code here :[link](https://github.com/HIT-Hampton/Atlas.git)

Comment: Are you familiar with how to run it in gdb? If so, when it segfaults you can type the command `bt` to get the full stack trace. In my stack trace the segfault actually happens in Eigen code but is last invoked by `CalcMassMatrix`(). It'd be good to confirm in your case as sll..

Comment: Oh~, I get it! I try to run it in gdb and get the same reason for the segfault. It is really caused by `CalcMassMatrix()`.   `Thread 1 "atlas_FloatingB" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6dc2b07 in drake::multibody::internal::MultibodyTree<double>::CalcMassMatrix(drake::systems::Context<double> const&, drake::EigenPtr<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >) const () from /opt/drake/lib/libdrake.so`

Comment: Ok, let me poke at my atlas segfault -- I'm willing to bet that whatever is causing my segfault is likely causing yours.

Comment: Sorry to bother you! Is there any method can help to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've been swamped and haven't had a chance to explore this. Let me see if I can't get someone to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I figure out that getting the contact results from "lcm-system" can avoid this problem. When simulating the atlas motion, the contact results are published to lcm-system in the "CONTACT_RESULTS" channel with type "lcmt_contact_results_for_viz". So, besides getting from output port of plant, we can also get it from lcm system.

First，add a LcmInterfaceSystem and LcmSubscriberSystem which subscribes "lcmt_contact_results_for_viz" type message of "CONTACT_RESULTS" channel from lcm-system, and connect it to the contact result input port of the controller leafsystem.

```
// Atlas.cpp
...
#include "drake/systems/lcm/lcm_subscriber_system.h"
#include "drake/systems/lcm/lcm_interface_system.h"
...


auto lcm = builder.AddSystem<systems::lcm::LcmInterfaceSystem>();
auto contact_sub = builder.AddSystem(
    systems::lcm::LcmSubscriberSystem::Make<lcmt_contact_results_for_viz>("CONTACT_RESULTS", lcm));
builder.Connect(contact_sub->get_output_port(),
    IDC->get_input_port_contact_result());
```

Then, declare the abstract input port in the controller, getting "lcmt_contact_results_for_viz" abstract value.

```
// Controller.h
#include "drake/lcm/drake_lcm.h"
#include "drake/lcm/drake_interface_.h"
#include "drake_lcmtypes/drake/lcmt_contact_results_for_rviz.hpp"
#icnlude "drake_lcmtypes/drake/lcmt_point_pair_contact_info_for_viz.hpp"
...
// Controller.cpp

input_port_index_contact_result_ = 
  this->DeclareAbstractInputPort("Contact Results", 
  Value<lcmt_contact_results_for_viz>()).get_value();
```

Finally, decode the message from abstract input port.

```
const AbstractValue* abstract_value = 
     this->EvalAbstractInput(context, input_port_index_contact_result_);
const auto& contact_result = 
     abstract_value->get_value<lcmt_contact_results_for_viz>();
// Operate the message...
```